# How save data in mongodb without specific req.bodys

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I discover that i don't need this:

```
var body = req.body;
var event = new EventModel({
        dateO: dateObject,
        date: body.date,
        name: body.name,
        type: body.type,
        meetingPoint: body.meetingPoint,
        info: body.info,
        men: body.men,
        women: body.women,
        description: body.description
    });

event.save.......
```

I can use just:

```
var event = new EventModel(req.body);
event.save.......
```

If all the inputs 'name' have the same name of my attr's in my database, mongoose can save just passing the req.body.

My question is:

I have in my HTML form the following inputs with the names:

```
date;
name;
type;
meetingPoint;
info;
men;
women;
description;
```

If i do just the `var event = new EventModel(req.body)`, will save this values, but there is a problem:

I have this dateO, and I need to deal with it in my backend.

I tried to do the following:

`req.body.dateO = what i want`. But i cant use the req.body in the controller.

How can i use just the:

`var event = new EventModel(req.body);` and still pass the dateO??

UPDATE:

I have the following schema:

```
var EventSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  dateO: {
    type: Date
  },
  date: String,
  name: String,
  meetingPoint: String,
  info: String,
  men: String,
  women: String,
  description: String,
});
```

And i have this html inputs:

```
<input name="date"/>
<input name="name"/>
<input name="type"/>
<input name="meetingpoint"/>
<input name="info"/> 
<input name="men"/>
<input name="women"/>
<input name="description"/>
```

It would be perfect if it were not for one problem:

I want use the input date field in the 'DD/MM/YYYY' format, and i cant, cause mongoose just except 'MM/DD/YYYY', so i am dealing with this problems like this:

```
var body = req.body;
var dateObject = new Date(body['date'].replace( /(\d{2})\/(\d{2})\/(\d{4})/, "$2/$1/$3"));
```

Them i can send like the way that i want to my database. My question is:

How can i send the dataO using the new event model in just one line:

`var event = new EventModel(req.body);`

Comment: So you probably could shorten the question to "how to handle dates in the request" as well as showing a sample of how the "body" fields are parsed from the form input as well as the Schema for your `EventModel`

Comment: You can, after instantiating your model with `var event = new EventModel(req.body);`, just do a `event.dateO = dateObject`.

Comment: not just dates, in my example i need for a date object, but could be a string as well..

Comment: i didn't catch @RodrigoMedeiros, can u please show me a example?

Comment: If you already have this `dateObject` to set the `dateO` field of your model, just set it with `event.dateO = dateObject;`. I imagine that the `dateO` field is defined in your schema file, right?

Comment: Can you please add information in your question rather than continue to comment. Because 1. You can probably just assign the value anyhow but 2. This may just be able to be handled by mongoose schema types anyway. You were asked to include additional information. Please do it.

Comment: not working @RodrigoMedeiros

Comment: Stop commenting so much it's too much noise. Now pick an option 1 . I or someone else could give you a lame answer and you can write some more bad code 2. Realise that the real problem is your choice of "DD/MM/YYY" as a string. The recommended HTML 5 and DatePicker types of interaction is to use a "timestamp" value in your form input. Mongoose will have no problem parsing a value directly.

Comment: i know that a good alternative is use date: with a date object type in my model, them use moment.js to format the date in my views.. but, i have this search input, and i need search for dates with this DD/MM/YYYY format, not the default format..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be using a `Date` object here directly and not setting other field. It would be much more simple for your client code to just use a timestamp value in the form, which can even be obtained from it's own `Date` object handler.

That' the clean good advice, but you just need some extra smarts in your schema to obtain a date object from the "string" in the Date field:

```
var EventSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  dateO: {
    type: Date
  },
  date: String,
  name: String,
  meetingPoint: String,
  info: String,
  men: String,
  women: String,
  description: String,
});

eventSchema.pre('save',function(next) {
  this.dateO = 
    new Date(this.date.replace( /(\d{2})\/(\d{2})\/(\d{4})/, "$2/$1/$3"));
  next();
});
```

So just move your logic into a "pre save" hook, and the field will be created based on the current data before the `.save()` is processed.

Comment: Thanks very much Neil, u are awesome!

Comment: Your solution is great Neil Lunn, but i took your advice. First i change the input for a datepicker, them i eliminate the dateO and setup the date to be a object date, them i use moment.js to deal with the format in my views, and for last, i'm using the new Date(etc.replace...) to change the date in the search field to the real format. Working 100%.